# How to apply aria-label in table cell

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsp, attributes

I have the following jsp and try to put attribute aria-label.

```
<td>
  <strong>abc</strong>
</td>
```

I try using div, but screen read unable to read "test".

```
<td>
   <div aria-label="test"><strong>abc</strong></div> 
</td>
```

I also try using span, screen reader does not read "test" as well.

```
<td>  
  <span aria-label="test"><strong>abc</strong></span> 
</td>
```

Any suggestion. Many many thanks.

Comment: Without using the word 'aria', can you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want screen reader reads "test abc".  I put aria-label="submit" to <button> tag, but it does not apply to table cell.

Comment: Did you try putting the attribute on the `<strong>` element?

Comment: Yes.  I did it as well.  Screen reader reads "abc" only.

Comment: Have a look at this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42681485/div-aria-label-not-being-read-by-jaws

Comment: I am new to jsp and css, actually, I read this before, but not understand "Put the aria-label directly on the control". should I write <td><div class="test"><strong>abc</strong></div></td>. create css .test{ }... something like that?

Comment: No, it's not a control.  A control is something interactive - it has actions and events, like buttons and text boxes.  You need to look at suggestion 2 in the accepted answer - an off-screen div that will get read, but is never visible.